# Proving equality on coinductive lazy lists in Coq

Tags: coq, lazy-sequences, coinduction

I am experimenting with Coq Coinductive types. I use the lazy list type form the Coq'Art book (sect. 13.1.4):

```
Set Implicit Arguments.

CoInductive LList (A:Set) : Set :=
| LNil : LList A
| LCons : A -> LList A -> LList A.
Implicit Arguments LNil [A].

CoFixpoint LAppend (A:Set) (u v:LList A) : LList A :=
  match u with
  | LNil => v
  | LCons a u' => LCons a (LAppend u' v)
  end.
```

In order to match the guard condition I also use the following decomposition functions form this book:

```
Definition LList_decomp (A:Set) (l:LList A) : LList A :=
  match l with
  | LNil => LNil
  | LCons a l' => LCons a l'
  end.


Lemma LList_decompose : forall (A:Set) (l:LList A), l = LList_decomp l.
Proof.
 intros.
 case l.
 simpl.
 reflexivity.
 intros.
 simpl. 
 reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The Lemma that `LNil` is left-neutral is easy to prove:

```
Lemma LAppend_LNil : forall (A:Set) (v:LList A), LAppend LNil v = v.
Proof.
 intros A v.
 rewrite LList_decompose with (l:= LAppend LNil v).
 case v.
 simpl.
 reflexivity.
 intros.
 simpl.
 reflexivity.
Qed.
```

But I got stuck by proving that `LNil` is also right-neutral:

```
Lemma LAppend_v_LNil : forall (A:Set) (v:LList A), LAppend v LNil = v.
```

After Arthur's answer, I tried with the new equality:

```
Lemma LAppend_v_LNil : forall (A:Set) (v:LList A), LListEq  (LAppend v LNil)  v.
Proof.
 intros.
 cofix.
 destruct v.
 rewrite LAppend_LNil.
 apply LNilEq.
```

Here I'm stuck. Coq's answer is:

```
1 subgoal
A : Set
a : A
v : LList A
LAppend_v_LNil : LListEq (LAppend (LCons a v) LNil) (LCons a v)
______________________________________(1/1)
LListEq (LAppend (LCons a v) LNil) (LCons a v)
```

After Eponier's answer I want to give it the final touch by introducing an Extensionality Axiom:

```
Axiom LList_ext: forall (A:Set)(l1 l2: LList A), (LListEq l1 l2 ) -> l1 = l2.
```

With that axiom I get the final cut of the Lemma:

```
Lemma LAppend_v_LNil : forall (A:Set) (v:LList A), (LAppend v LNil) = v.
Proof.
 intros.
 apply LList_ext.
 revert v.
   cofix.
   intros.
   destruct v. Guarded. (* now we can safely destruct v *)
   - rewrite LAppend_LNil.
     constructor.
   - rewrite (LList_decompose (LAppend _ _)).
     simpl. constructor. apply LAppend_v_LNil.
Qed.
```

Now, here are my final questions for this thread:

- Does such an axiom already exist in some Coq library?
- Is that axiom consistent with Coq?
- With what standard axioms of Coq (e.g. classic, UIP, fun ext, Streicher K) is that axiom inconsistent?

Comment: A similar [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63197/is-extensionality-for-coinductive-datatypes-consistent-with-coqs-logic) has been recently asked on [CS.SE] site. Nobody answered yet (as of time of this comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple rule is to use `cofix` as soon as possible in your proofs.

Actually, in your proof of `LAppend_v_LNil`, the guarded condition is already violated at `destruct v`. You can check this fact using the command `Guarded`, which helps testing before the end of the proof if all the uses of coinduction hypotheses are legit.

```
Lemma LAppend_v_LNil : forall (A:Set) (v:LList A), LListEq  (LAppend v LNil)  v.
  intros.
  cofix.
  destruct v. Fail Guarded.
Abort.
```

You should actually swap `intros` and `cofix`. From there, the proof is not difficult.

EDIT: here is the complete solution.

```
Lemma LAppend_v_LNil : forall (A:Set) (v:LList A), LListEq (LAppend v LNil)  v.
  cofix.
  intros.
  destruct v. Guarded. (* now we can safely destruct v *)
  - rewrite LAppend_LNil.
    constructor.
  - rewrite (LList_decompose (LAppend _ _)).
    simpl. constructor. apply LAppend_v_LNil.
Qed.
```

Comment: It would be great if you could post your solution.

Answer (score 5):

You guessed it right: just like for functions, Coq's generic notion of equality is too weak to be useful for most coinductive types.  If you want to prove your result, you need to replace `eq` by a coinductive notion of equality for lists; for instance:

```
CoInductive LListEq (A:Set) : LList A -> LList A -> Prop :=
| LNilEq : LListEq A LNil LNil
| LConsEq x lst1 lst2 : LListEq A lst1 lst2 -> 
  LListEq A (LCons x lst1) (LCons x lst2).
```

Manipulating infinite objects is a vast topic in Coq. If you want to learn more, Adam Chlipala's CPDT has an entire [chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.Coinductive.html) on coinduction.

Comment: Thank you. I've extended the question by using the new equality.