# Ltac call to "cofix" failed. Error: All methods must construct elements in coinductive types

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coinduction

```
Require Import Streams.

CoFixpoint map {X Y : Type} (f : X -> Y) (s : Stream X) : Stream Y :=
  Cons (f (hd s)) (map f (tl s)).

CoFixpoint interleave {X : Type} (s : Stream X * Stream X) : Stream X := Cons (hd (fst s)) (Cons (hd (snd s)) (interleave (tl (fst s), tl (snd s)))).

Lemma map_interleave : forall {X Y : Type} (f : X -> Y) (s1 s2 : Stream X), map f (interleave (s1, s2)) = interleave (map f s1, map f s2).
Proof.
  Fail cofix. (* error *)
Abort.
```

Output:

```
Ltac call to "cofix" failed.
Error: All methods must construct elements in coinductive types.
```

I'm not sure what this means - both `map` and `interleave` are straightforward corecursive functions building values of coinductive types. What's the problem?

Comment: This is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39882575/2747511).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that `=` notation stands for `eq`, which is an inductive type, *not* a coinductive one.

Instead, you can show that the streams `map f (interleave (s1, s2))` and `interleave (map f s1, map f s2)` are extensionally equal. Here is an excerpt from the Coq reference manual ([§1.3.3](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual003.html#CoInductiveTypes))

> In order to prove the extensionally equality of two streams `s1` and `s2` we have to construct an infinite proof of equality, that is, an infinite object of type `EqSt s1 s2`.

After changing `eq` to `EqSt` we can prove the lemma:

```
Lemma map_interleave : forall {X Y : Type} (f : X -> Y) (s1 s2 : Stream X),
  EqSt (map f (interleave (s1, s2))) (interleave (map f s1, map f s2)).
Proof.
  cofix.
  intros X Y f s1 s2.
  do 2 (apply eqst; [reflexivity |]).
  case s1 as [h1 s1], s2 as [h2 s2].
  change (tl (tl (map f (interleave (Cons h1 s1, Cons h2 s2))))) with
         (map f (interleave (s1, s2))).
  change (tl (tl (interleave (map f (Cons h1 s1), map f (Cons h2 s2))))) with
         (interleave (map f s1, map f s2)).
  apply map_interleave.
Qed.
```

By the way, many tricks dealing with coinductive datatypes can be found in [this](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.Coinductive.html) CPDT chapter.